# Using the ColorPanel in the NSToolbar in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, nstoolbar, nscolorpanel

I just started learning swift and I am trying to create an app that changes the color of the background based on the color selected in the NSColorPanel in the NSToolbar.

[image: Toolbar Colors]

When clicking on `Colors` I am faced a Color Palette. Now what I can't figure out is how to extract/read the Color Codes in Swift.

I have looked all over the internet but unfortunately nothing was helpful.

Hopefully someone here can provide with more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to add an observer for when the color panel has changed colors.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(colorPanelDidChange(_:)),
                         name: NSColorPanel.colorDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

where `colorPanelDidChange` is your custom method:

```
@objc func colorPanelDidChange(_ notification: NSNotification)
```

In this method, you extract the content of the notification:

```
if let cp = notification.object as? NSColorPanel
```

and now you can do `cp.color` to get the actual color the user has clicked on.